# TLS version support

Tags: encryption

I am trying to backtrack the versions of TLS support on Android.

More in detail:

From which version of Android started TLS 1.0 support 
From which version of Android started TLS 1.1 support 
From which version of Android started TLS 1.2 support

If you could also supply me with some affordable info source I'd be grateful - I know this was quite a newbie question, I'm sorry for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't successfull just using google, have a look in the android open source project aosp. You will find openssl and the answer to your question.

There is a nice page which allows for very fast searches inside aosp:
http://androidxref.com/source/